# In the scikit-multiflow EvaluatePrequential class, what is the difference between the paramter n_wait and batch_size?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, data-stream

My first understanding was that batch_size is basically all needed to first test the model(s) on new incoming data and then train it/them on the new data. So, how does n_wait influence that procedure?

Docs: [evaluate_prequential](https://scikit-multiflow.github.io/scikit-multiflow/skmultiflow.evaluation.evaluate_prequential.html)

My first guess would be that n_wait does not change the procedure, but only influences how the metrics are caculated. Would you agree?

Bonus: is there a integrated way to handle variable batch sizes in multiflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `batch_size` parameter corresponds to the number of data samples passed to the model(s) on each `test` and `train` operation.

As you mention, the `n_wait` parameter is used to control the amount of data to be considered when evaluating the "current" performance (last `n` samples). Additionally, it is used to control the refresh rate of the evaluation plot.

For the bonus question, `EvaluatePrequential` does not support variable batch sizes. However, available learning methods can handle this scenario.